# NeoTree: Open to CWD of Buffer

Tags: directories, project

Occasionally when I'm navigating around I want Neotree to jump to the folder of the file I'm working in, but when I open Neotree it's still the last place I left it.  I can't find any function with M-x to jump to pwd.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself!  Must have been invisible before:  'neotree-projectile-action